# Cycle through classes on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm in the process of creating a slider which is essentially 4 circles that when you click the next button change size and position. Here it is the working: http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/people.html

It works fine when you click the next button but isn't reversing when clicking the back button. Can anyone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var steps = ['right-center', 'bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'left', 'left-center', 'top', ],
    allClasses = steps.join(' ');
  $('.animate-slider.next').click(function() {
    $('#a').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[0]);
    $('#b').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[1]);
    $('#c').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[2]);
    $('#d').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[3]);
    $('#e').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[4]);
    $('#f').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[5]);
    steps.push(steps.shift()); // move first element to the end

    // to rotate the other direction you would pop and unshift instead
    // steps.unshift(steps.pop()); // move last element to the beginning
  });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
  var steps = ['right-center', 'bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'left', 'left-center', 'top', ],
    allClasses = steps.join(' ');
  $('.animate-slider.back').click(function() {
    $('#a').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[0]);
    $('#b').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[1]);
    $('#c').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[2]);
    $('#d').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[3]);
    $('#e').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[4]);
    $('#f').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[5]);
   steps.unshift(steps.pop()); // move first element to the end

    // to rotate the other direction you would pop and unshift instead
    // steps.unshift(steps.pop()); // move last element to the beginning
  });
```

Comment: It's not working as it should. If you click the next button a few times then go back it messes up the order and sets it back to the start :( So frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the id from each circle and add a class "circle" instead

```js
$(function() {

  currentState = 0;
 
  var steps = ['right-center', 'bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'left', 'left-center', 'top', ],
    allClasses = steps.join(' ');
  
  $('.circle').each(function(i){
     $(this).addClass(steps[i]);
  });
  $('.animate-slider.next').click(function() {
    currentState++;
    $('.circle').each(function(i) {
      console.log((currentState + i) % steps.length);
      $(this).removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[(currentState + i) % steps.length]);
    });
  });

  
  $('.animate-slider.back').click(function() {
    currentState --;
    currentState = currentState<=0 ? steps.length-Math.abs(currentState): currentState;
    
    $('.circle').each(function(i) {
      console.log((currentState + i) % steps.length, currentState, i);
      $(this).removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[(currentState + i) % steps.length]);
    });
  });


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <a class="animate-slider next">Next</a>
  <a class="animate-slider back">Back</a>
</div>
<div class="circles">
            <div data-offset="-10" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(1.59031px) translateY(13.4848px);">
             <span class="team-1 active">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-2">Be Authentic</span>
                <span class="team-3">Express the brand values, not yourself</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span>
            </div>
            <div id="b" data-offset="10" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(-1.59031px) translateY(-13.4848px);">
            <span class="team-1 active">UX as branding</span>
                <span class="team-2">Every step of the process, every time</span>
                <span class="team-3">Complicate, then clarify</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span></div>
            <div id="c" data-offset="15" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(-2.38547px) translateY(-20.2273px);">
            <span class="team-1 active">Analytics, SEO &amp; PP</span>
                <span class="team-2">Be engaging</span>
                <span class="team-3">Restriction is freedom</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span></div>
            <div id="d" data-offset="-5" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(0.795157px) translateY(6.74242px);">
            <span class="team-1 active">Be holistic</span>
                <span class="team-2">Be distinctive</span>
                <span class="team-3">What’s the story?</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span></div>
            <div id="e" data-offset="-15" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(2.38547px) translateY(20.2273px);">
            <span class="team-1 active">Functionality</span>
                <span class="team-2">Be practical</span>
                <span class="team-3">Beware fashion</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span></div>
            <div id="f" data-offset="-10" class="ball circle" style="transform: translateX(1.59031px) translateY(13.4848px);">
            <span class="team-1 active">Risk management</span>
                <span class="team-2">Risk management</span>
                <span class="team-3">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-4">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-5">Core objectives</span>
                <span class="team-6">Core objectives</span></div>
          </div>
```

This example ve the css [LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNxmEb)

Comment: Hey Vanojx, thanks for that. Really appreciate it. I've added what you said but it's still not working as it should. When clicking back it's now removing the classes all together and if you click next the order isn't right.

Comment: sorry!! i ve seen the error.... i ve edited. Now it should work as expected.... but you ve to remove the steps classes from the DOM

Comment: Hi, do you know how big of a task is it to click on a circle and get it to rotate to the 'bottom-left' with the others cycling depending on where it is?

Comment: try with a little trick... set a click event on the circle and then trigger the next event until that circle ve the class "bottom-left";

Comment: Thanks Vanojx. My expertise in Javascript is very low and i'm struggling to make a start in what you're suggesting. Would it be okay to give me an example to play with please? I will buy you a beer somehow :P

Comment: lel.... add this $('.circle').on("click",function(){ while(!$(this).hasClass("bottom-left")){$('.animate-slider.next').trigger("click")}}); ..... say thanks with a beer is always appreciated ;)

Comment: Cheers mate! I've added that but it's now crashing the page. http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/people.html let me know where i can donate to you mate :)

Comment: oh thats strange.... i tried it in the fiddle and works very well..... maybe there is some kind of conflict with other scripts on the page